# JQuery: Need a widget that displays new image after a fixed amount of time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I don't know exactly how it's called (Image-timer??? I'm not sure), but here are the functionalities.

Let's say I have a div where I need to display a group of images in loop, one at time (each 5 seconds, for instance). On top of that, I'd like some effects, such as fading out when an image replace an other.

Can someone point me to a Jquery widget that does that or tell me if I can get that using JQuery?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try s3Slider - http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration.html.  It is a really slick jQuery plugin that will do exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the setInterval function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="clock" />
<script language=javascript>
var int=self.setInterval("clock()",1000);
function clock()
  {
  var d=new Date();
  var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("clock").value=t;
  }
</script>
</form>
<button onclick="int=window.clearInterval(int)">Stop</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Based on that you can change the image's src and do fading effects every X seconds.

Comment: (+1) I like this method best - Since you get more control over what your function does and the overhead it incurres.

Comment: thanks. imho it's better to avoid using plugins when the feature needed is so simple

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for a slideshow plugin. I use this one it has everything you asked for [JQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this out :  [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html)

It can give you more than a dozen of effects, allows you to specify the timeout and animation speed.